# Applications of Derivatives;Fabricating a Box

Tags: derivatives

An open-top box is to be made by cutting small congruent squares from the corners of a 12-in.by-12-in. sheet of tin and 
bending up the sides  .How large should the squares cut from the corners be to make the box hold as much as possible?

solution:

I start with a picture .In the figure , the corner square are x in. on a side . The volume of the box is a function of this variable:

$V(x)=4x(12-2x)+(12-2x)^2=48x-8x^2+144-48x+4x^2=144-4x^2$

then

$\frac{dV}{dx}=-8x$

$\Longrightarrow \frac{dV}{dx}=0 \Longrightarrow x=0$

$\Longrightarrow V(0)=144$

The maximum volume is 144 in.$^3$.The cutout squares should be 0 in. on a side.

But this way is wrong,why?

Right way:

I start with a picture .In the figure,the corner square are x in. on a side.The volume of the box is a function of this variable:

$V(x)=x(12-2x)^2=144x-48x^2+4x^3$

then

$\frac{dV}{dx}=144-96x+12x^2=12(12-8x+x^2=12(2-x)(6-x)$

Since the sides of the sheet of tin are only 12 in. long,$x\leq 6$ and the domain of $V$ is the interval $0\leq x\leq 6$ .

Endpoint values:$V(0)=0, V(6)=0$

Critical-point value:$V(2)=128$ .

The maximum volume is 128 in.$^3$.The cutout squares should be 2 in. on a side.

Comment: The second method is correct, I solved it the same way. In the first try, you calculated the volume $V(x)$ wrong. I don't understand why you got $4x(12-2x) + (12-2x)^2$... That looks like the surface area of the cutout, not the volume of the formed box.

Comment: Thanks for your comment